# Adding reference (e.g by adding "using system.web" ) once for multiple libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, using

Is there a way to put all "using" statements used on top of each cs file in a common file and then reference that common file?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please note that references and `using` directives are actually two distinct concepts.

Comment: The short answer here is "no, there is not - directives must be per-file (except for some ASP.NET scenarios where you can cheat)"